# ASP.Net core Release version

Tags: asp.net-core

I am confused with ASP.NET Core Release version. If I go to downloads I see
https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windowsvs2015 I see tools as a preview version
but what about ASP.NET CORE which is the latest release version ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this [page](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core).
The LTS version is 1.0.1 but you can choose the current version 1.1.0 (not LTS yet).

Comment: If I go to Linux deployment in the link you provided (https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/linux) why it shows as (dotnet-dev-1.0.0-preview2 package for Ubuntu 14.04 ?

Comment: @user3615869 in this [link](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#linuxubuntu) you can find the following info: "To install .NET Core 1.1 on Ubuntu or Linux Mint, simply use apt-get.". There's also this info: ".NET Core 1.1 is the latest version. For long term support (LTS) versions and additional downloads check the all Linux downloads section."